# How do I send logging info in the body of an email?

Tags: django

I'm using Django logging. Below is how I am currently calling the Django logging.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
.
.
.
logger.info("Database results")
```

Below is my Django logging config from the settings.py file.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'email_admins': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': False,
        },
        'admin_console': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default'
        },
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'file_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter':'default',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename':'logs/prj_log',
            'when':'midnight',
            'interval':1,
        },
        'request_handler': {
                'level':'ERROR',
                'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': 'logs/django_request.log',
                'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
                'backupCount': 5,
                'formatter':'default',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['email_admins', 'file_handler', 'admin_console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers':['null'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        },
        'django.request': { 
            'handlers': ['email_admins', 'request_handler'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

I get an email with `Database results` as the subject. How do I add further information to the body of the email?

Comment: what is your logging configuration?

Comment: @Marat updated with logging config

Comment: Hey, I was looking for the same thing. This answer solves the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13940055/311829

Answer (score 1):

django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler only logs stacktraces as email message (see handler code for more details). So if you want to log something at info level, you need to write your own handler sending emails.

Even with a custom handler, you can not log two parameters (eg subject and message text) at once. As you probably want to log a serialized objects, you will have to hardcode the subject

Answer (score -1):

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```